# Cordova android emulator "cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: android, cordova

Have just installed the latest version of Apache Cordova (7.0.1) on Windows, the Android SDK, added the android platform, and when trying to run the android emulator it compiles everything ok but then shows a:

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Without indication or anything else to trace the error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the [Ionic framework forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-android/93297/11) found the following answer that solved the problem:

> Tracked it down to file /platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js
>   line 202:
>
> var num = target.split('(API level ')[1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-android/93297/11).replace(')', '');
>
> Replace it with a regex search and extraction:
>
> var num = target.match(/\d+/)[0];

Comment: @Hauke: link added in answer!

Comment: reported: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12981?jql=text%20~%20%22cannot%20read%20property%20'%22

Comment: Awesome! It would be interesting to know how to debug that. The verbose output wasn't much use.

Comment: This is the only solution that I found online which actually works.

Comment: Beware that this fix will not propagate to project version control as it does not alter the underlying cordova-android npm package.

Comment: Worked for me :P

Answer (score 5):

Happened with me this week.
Try to downgrade Android platform to 6.0.0 until ionic team resolve this issue.

Commands:

```
cordova platform rm Android
cordova platform add Android@6.0.0
```

Comment: it was not an ionic issue, though the solution was found in their forum. It is a cordova issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd rather not modify emulator.js (Adrian's answer), I was able to work around this issue by manually starting an Android virtual device before running `cordova emulate android`.

Answer (score 2):

**Device Info**

- Windows 10
- Ionic 3

**Command**

I ran the following command on Windows 10 using ionic and had the same issue:

ionic cordova emulate android

**Error**

The following error was reported in the terminal:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.775 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/ionic/quoteapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Arduino2\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_144
Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

**Fix**

The replacement of:

```
var num = target.split('(API level ')1.replace(')', '');
```

with

```
var num = target.match(/\d+/)[0]
```

as noted above worked.

The file in an ionic project is found in your ionic app folder in the following directory: /platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js

***I did not come up with this fix, just wanted to provide what command and error I got to help others.***